# Convert VelodyneScan to PointCloud2 from a rosbag file

Tags: ros, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to build a 3D map from `velodyne_points (sensor_msgs/PointCloud2)` in **offline** mode. In order to save some storage space, I am logging only `velodyne_packets (velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan)` to a rosbag file using [velodyne_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver?distro=hydro). Later, I need to convert this *VelodyneScan* into *PointCloud2* to build the map.

So my question is: **How to convert VelodyneScan into PointCloud2 when the device is no connected?** I was trying [velodyne_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud?distro=hydro) that works fine only when the sensor (Velodyne) is connected. Otherwise, it does not publish `/velodyne_points`.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191972/convert-velodynescan-to-pointcloud2-from-a-rosbag-file/) by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2014-09-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-05**:
how you are running velodyne_pointploud

**Comment by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on 2014-09-05**:
I am playing back the rosbag file as `rosbag play --clock file_name.bag` and then launching the `cloud_nodelet.launch` file located in the [velodyne_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud?distro=indigo) package. cont ...

**Comment by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on 2014-09-05**:
In the launch file, I am assigning the value `"$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/params/32db.yaml"` to the parameter `"calibration"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

add node output on screen, hope it gives whats the problem is.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on 2014-09-05**:
In addition to this, I also need to run **nodelet manager** from `velodyne_driver` package.